# Non transactional methods are also called by proxy, how to avoid that?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to spring and I found an interesting behavior but don't know how to fix it... I have a class as following:

@Component 
public class ScheduleService {

```
/** The Constant log. */
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleService.class);

/** The schedule repository. */
@Autowired
private ScheduleRepository  scheduleRepository;

@Autowired
private PipelineService pipelineService;


private AtomicReference     atomic_scheduler = new AtomicReference();

/**
 * Instantiates a new schedule service.
 */
public ScheduleService() {
}

/**
 * Starts the quarts scheduler instance
 * 
 */
public synchronized void start() {
    ....
}

public Scheduler getScheduler() {
    start();
    return (Scheduler) atomic_scheduler.get();
}

/**
 * Creates the schedule.
 *
 * @param session the session
 * @param schedule the Schedule
 * @return the Schedule
 */
public Schedule createSchedule(Session session, Schedule schedule) throws Exception {
```

..........
    }

```
/**
 * Gets the Schedule.
 *
 * @param session the session
 * @param id the id
 * @return the Schedule
 */
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Schedule getSchedule(Session session, String id) throws Exception {
```

.....
    }

```
/**
 * Gets the Schedule given the Schedule name.
 *
 * @param session the session
 * @param name the name of the Schedule to return
 * @return the Schedule
 */
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Schedule getScheduleByName(Session session, String name) throws Exception {
    ........
}

/**
 */
public Schedule updateSchedule(Session session, Schedule sch) throws Exception {
```

.......
    }
}

I found all methods in this class are called by proxy but I don't know why... Should only "transactional" method be called by APO proxy? How do I solve this? I want non-transactional methods invoked by calling threads directly without going through proxy.

Thanks everyone for advise.

Comment: No... A proxy is created for the whole object not a subset of that (nor is that possible afaik). But only the transactional methods will have the advice applied the others won't.

Comment: Why do you not want the methods to be called via proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is impossible to have only some of the methods called via proxy.

To implement the AOP behavior (in your case @Transactional) Spring has to build a proxy around your object so it can intercept invocations of the annotated methods. For this to work Spring must than inject the proxy instead of your object everywhere.

So every other object only knows the proxy. And all calls can only be made trough the proxy.

How should it be possible to have only the transactional calls go through the proxy? This would require quite a lot of byte code manipulation to find all calls to methods on your object and than start redirecting them somehow depending on if they are transactional. Also keep in mind that Spring does not only support singleton beans. With multiple instances of a class it must also figure out to witch object to delegate to. It is a lot easier to just inject the proxy everywhere and than let Java work normally from there.

If you want more details you might want to take a look at `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` and try building a proxy yourself. That would give you an idea how Java Dynamic Proxies actually work. (If I am not mistaken Spring also uses this class by default for its proxies.)